# StreamController.close() doesn't cause done event to emit

Tags: stream, dart

This is a stream that doesn't work (my own):

```
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> generateNumbers() {
  StreamController<int> controller;
  controller = StreamController(
      onListen: () {
        for (final number in [1, 2]) {
          controller.add(number);
        }
        controller.close();
      },
      onCancel: () => controller.close());
  return controller.stream;
}

void main() async {
  await for (final _ in generateNumbers()) {
    print('in');
  }
  print('out');
}
```

This is a stream that does work (taken from [here](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/creating-streams)): https://privatebin.net/?dfbc5965db5c57b1#wru/1BPk4Zp7LbT/kkomgnx8ruchbxAROyn9vFbjZbc=

They are both supposed to print `in`, `in`, `out`, but mine doesn't print `out` (since it never gets out of the `await for` loop).

Comment: Interesting. If you use `Stream<int> generateNumbers() => Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]);` it works as expected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yea, that's probably because it uses the core library without me messing with it. I can get my streams to emit done if I simply use `yield number;` (and not use a `StreamController` to deal with yielding). This is of course a dumbed down sample of my actual streams, none of which work. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I looked a bit into it but wasn't able to figure out what the issue is. I guess you'll have to wait until lrn finds the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected, but only because of an insidious interaction between `onCancel` and `controller.close`.

When you call `controller.close` it returns a future which is completed when the controller is done. The controller is done when it has delivered all events and/or it has been cancelled and the call to `onCancel` has completed.

The line `onCancel: () => controller.close()` sets you up in a situation where the future returned by `controller.close()` is completed only after the same future has been completed. So, it never completes. That future is also returned by `onCancel`, so the loop, which apparently calls `cancel` on the way out, never completes either.

I think we should look into how this is working. The loop should not call `cancel` after receiving a `done` event.

You should also drop the `onCancel` argument. There is no need to close a controller when it has already been `cancelled` - nobody will receive the done event anyway.